# C# how to show time with stopwatch in a listbox?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I'm trying to measure execution time of bubble sort using random ints and i need to show those values in a list box but it only shows "system.Diagnostics.stopwatch" probably there's something wrong with my code but i don't know what, sorry I'm new to this, the code im using:

```
    {
       
        Stopwatch tiempo = new Stopwatch();
        Random NumArrRandom = new Random();
      

        int IMPRIME_DE_NUMERO = 1000000, IMPRIME_A_NUMERO = 10000000;
        int POSICION_DE = 100, A_POSICION = 5000;
        int[] Vector = Enumerable.Repeat(POSICION_DE, A_POSICION).Select(i => NumArrRandom.Next(IMPRIME_DE_NUMERO, IMPRIME_A_NUMERO)).ToArray();
        int temp, n = Vector.Length;
      
        foreach (var objeto in Vector) { listBox1.Items.Add(objeto.ToString()); }

      
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            tiempo.Start();
            
            //DateTime tiempo1 = DateTime.Now;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (Vector[i] < Vector[j])
                {
                    //////////////////////////
                    temp = Vector[j];      //////
                    Vector[j] = Vector[i]; ////////
                    Vector[i] = temp;      //////
                    tiempo.Stop();         ////
                    //DateTime tiempoStop = DateTime.Now;
                    /////////////////////////

                }
            }
        }
         //====================================================================
       // TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan();
        foreach (var objeto in Vector)enter image description here
        {
           
            listBox2.Items.Add(objeto.ToString()); listBox3.Items.Add(tiempo.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just read how to use stopwatch - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: This is happening because you can't just convert a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1) object into something useful via `.ToString()`. Most types do not override the `.ToString()` method, and the default implementation (on `object`) is to just return the type name. Instead, you should look on the properties of the Stopwatch, such as Elapsed and get the data you want from there.

Comment: Let this be a lesson: if you find yourself using `.ToString()` at any point, think to yourself "is there a better way?" because the answer is almost always "yes"

Comment: btw, your implementation won't work correctly. You need to persist stopwatch calculation from `for` loop in some array, and then write values from there. Otherwise, you will write the last calculation everytime